# php mysql insert query having trouble

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a query which is not inserting if i use the where clause, without the where clause it inserts data. this is weird and I have never seen it happen before in WAMP

`$key=substr(md5(rand(0, 1000000)), 0, 5)`;

```
$key1="INSERT INTO login(key_id) VALUES('$key') 
WHERE (email_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email_id']) . "')"

if(mysql_query($key1))  
{
   $message = 'User Added!.';
   echo "<SCRIPT>
   alert('$message');
   location='forgotpassword.php';
   </SCRIPT>";     
}
```

If I echo `$_POST['email_id']` it does return valid result

Comment: I think you need `update` query instead of `insert`!!

Comment: You cannot `INSERT`an existing row (the `WHERE` tries to select an existing row(s) )

Comment: Thanks saty and ubercoder. I am not even sure how i forgot this. i need to use update to update existing row instead .. urrgghhhh  full day gone in this simple piece of code |

Comment: Also since nobody mentioned it I will. Stop using the mysql_* extension as it is deprecated as of PHP version 5.5.0 and is deleted as of PHP version 7.0 instead use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and also your code is open to [SQL-injections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) use prepared statements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

INSERT and WHERE do not mix.
when INSERTing, you are creating a new record.
WHERE is used with SELECTing DELETEing or UPDATEing, when you have to specify a filter which rows you want to SELECT, DELETE or UPDATE.

if you want to INSERT a row, do not use WHERE.
if you want to change a row, use

```
$key1="UPDATE login SET key_id = '$key' WHERE
 (email_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email_id']) . "')";
```

Comment: That said, it should be noted that mysql_functions are deprecated, and in PHP7 removed - you should switch to mysqli_ or PDO instead

Comment: Franz, Thanks for the update. I am really dumb. I need the update query as mentioned by saty above and also by you that insert and where dont go together. I had a question will my code stop wroking if php is updated to 7 ?

Comment: all mysql_ functions are removed in PHP7, so: yes. but mysqli_ offers everything mysql_ does and more, while PDO offers a very powerful abstraction layer with which you can use the same functions for mysql, pgsql, mssql, CSV-files and many, many, more.

Comment: @ABI: if its work than please accept this answer. it will help for others who facing the same issue. good work Franz...

Answer (score 1):

`Insert` is only used on creating new record and `where` clause is only used if want to set any condition it is used with like `select`,`update`,`delete`.

Try this it will help:-

```
  $key1="update login set key_id ='$key' WHERE 
           (email_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email_id']) . "')";
```

Comment: guess you forgot to replace INSERT with UPDATE? [comment obsolete after answer got edited]

Answer (score 0):

I know @Franz-Gleichmann is already explained very well, whats wrong in your code.

You need to use `UPDATE` for updating data modified code:

```
$key1 = "UPDATE login SET key_id = '$key' WHERE
(email_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email_id']) . "')";
```

Now i am adding two more points:

- Please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`, because `mysql_*` is deprecated and not available in PHP 7.
- You missed the termination semi colon on the same line, i hope this is typo error.